# Get value from field odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

My source:

```
data = self.read(cr, uid, ids,['date','user_id'], context=context)
        user_id = data[0]['user_id']
        print(user_id)
```

In console line I get **(8, u'admin')**

How get only number 8 without name?

Comment: Did you try using the `search` method?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas No, Can you help me how integrate in my example?

Comment: print(user_id[0])

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas  Tnx a lot of....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with these

```
user_id = data[0] and data[0]['user_id'] and data[0]['user_id'][0]
```

It will return *8*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user_id = data[0]['user_id'][0]
```

hope this helps.

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'